# Best way to handle static/constant values in Mule config

Tags: mule

What is the best way to handle static/constant values in Mule config? I have a many flows that utilize expressions that need some static values. I was thinking of just creating a simple Java class to hold these and using MEL to access them. But is there a better way and possibly just using Mule config? Maybe set flowVars everytime for these values or use spring propety placeholders?

Comment: Would the mule-app.properties file meet your needs? You could just reference them using ${propertyName}.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store these values in a properties file and use them with `${ }` placeholders in your expressions.

Answer (score 0):

@jonlee I would use spring property placeholder. [here](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Using+Parameters+in+Your+Configuration+Files)  is the reference doc